# whats going on with fdisk?

Tags: partitioning, mount, devices, fdisk

I was trying to find the device mount point of my smart phone, when I ran sudo fdisk -l and saw something more curious.

```
...
Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9f712909

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 974782463 974780416 464.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       974784510 976771071   1986562   970M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       974784512 976771071   1986560   970M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

whats with having /dev/ram0-15? I only have 8GB of ram, why is it all busted up like this? Ive never seen output like this before, what does it mean to have all these ram devices?

UPDATE:
ok, apparently its to do with using wily-werewolf, and there is an explaination here: [fdisk -l shows 16 ram disks /dev/ram0 ... /ram15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703576/ubuntu-15-10-fdisk-l-shows-16-ram-disks-dev-ram0-ram15)

Thats great, but it doesn’t say how to get the old fdisk -l output back. 
I’m  not interested in the current output having 16 ram disks listed. How can i make fdisk give the output formerly associated with fdisk -l omitting all the ram disk stuff?

Comment: I haven't checked the code, but the `-l` option to `fdisk`, when used without a disk device, probably goes through all the disk devices. Because RAM disks *are* disk devices, they get included. The same thing happens if you use LVM -- `fdisk -l` tries to parse them, too. If you really want to limit the output, you'll need to write a wrapper script or change the command. For instance, `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?` will probably do what you want. That would omit things like SD cards (`/dev/mmcblk?` devices), though.

Comment: -l never used to show the ram disks though. This is a new issue, caused by changes in in Wily.  maybe I can get an older version of fdisk...

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the output shown by `fdisk` (excluding the RAM disks) by using the following:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd*
```

or, on older systems:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/hd*
```